# JDBC connecting MySQL script need help using ScriptRunner

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a Java application and i need it to connect with my MySQL database's SQL script using JDBC.

Here is my Java application:

```java
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package basic;
import basic.ScriptRunner;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class javaconnect {
    Connection conn = null;
    public static Connection ConnectDb(){
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new","login","pass");
/*As we are creating a connection on a local computer we will write the url as jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 */
ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(conn, false, false);
runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D://Java Lenti/EkonomiSoftware/src/basic/new.sql")));

return conn ;
}
catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
return null;}


}

}
```

The problem is that the Java application connects through MySQL Server, not through the SQL Script. I think the problem is at Connection parameters I gave. Can anyone guide me how to change the connection to make it connect to the SQL script not to the server?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
package com.spring.sample.controller;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager
                    .getConnection(
                            "",
                            "", "");

            ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(conn, false, false);
            runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("new.sql")));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

new.sql

```
insert into hello(name) values ('test');
```

May be there're some mistakes at your sql file.

Comment: what should i put at .getConnection()?

Comment: It's your host, username, password